# Angular 2 - ngModel not updated from datepicker

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have an input that is bound to a value in the model.

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentDate">
```

I have a datepicker that I use to populate this input.  When a value is chosen from via the datepicker the input does not seem to update the model as its not firing a pipe farther down in the code.

**However**, if I manually type into the input field then the the ngModel does seem to update as the pipe then fires to filter based on the new value.  I have bound an 'on change' handler to the input, which fires when typing or when using the datepicker.

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
        //Fires on change
    })
```

Is there a way to trigger the ngModel change event manually, or is there more elegant solution someone else is aware of?

Comment: Does the `changeDate` fires when you change date from datepicker? Have you tried  setting currentDate from the `changeDate` event?

Comment: Using the date picker event to correct the value does work.  Feels a little clumsy having to manually bind that, but if it works, it works.

Thanks Madhu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the datepicker's own events I was able to just manually update the model value.

```
AttachDateChangeHandler(): void {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', (e)=> {
        this.currentDate = e.date.***()
    })
}
```

Thanks to Madhu Ranjan for the suggestion.

Comment: What are the *'s in e.date.***()? I'm getting an error here

Comment: @Brett You'll want to convert that to which ever date format you want.  I use e.date.toLocaleDateString()

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, triggering Angular2's change-detection..

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNhoOiZKYXc1z3RId6b5?p=preview)

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $('#myinput').val("changed..");

    var evt = new Event("input", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});

    $('#myinput')[0].dispatchEvent(evt);

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar of Primeng is very useful https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar